# How to pass a Bundle to Android Wear using MessageApi

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm currently passing Bytes to AnroidWear using:

```
 MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), path, text.getBytes() ).await();
```

I want to send a proper Data Bundle to my Wearable, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your bundle to bytes, and on receiver, convert bytes to Bundle.

With this **simple** method, you can send only **String** Bundle values.

(And, It seems that you can convert Bundle to String with GSON and BundleTypeAdapterFactory also, but I'm not tested.)

```
public void example() {
    // Value
    Bundle inBundle = new Bundle();
    inBundle.putString("key1", "value");
    inBundle.putInt("key2", 1); // will be failed
    inBundle.putFloat("key3", 0.5f); // will be failed
    inBundle.putString("key4", "this is key4");

    // From Bundle to bytes
    byte[] inBytes = bundleToBytes(inBundle);

    // From bytes to Bundle
    Bundle outBundle = jsonStringToBundle(new String(inBytes));

    // Check values
    String value1 = outBundle.getString("key1"); // good
    int value2 = outBundle.getInt("key2"); // fail
    float value3 = outBundle.getFloat("key3"); // fail
    String value4 = outBundle.getString("key4"); // good

}


private byte[] bundleToBytes(Bundle inBundle) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    Set<String> keys = inBundle.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        try {
            json.put(key, inBundle.get(key));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //Handle exception here
        }
    }

    return json.toString().getBytes();
}


public static Bundle jsonStringToBundle(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        return jsonToBundle(jsonObject);
    } catch (JSONException ignored) {

    }
    return null;
}

public static Bundle jsonToBundle(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Iterator iter = jsonObject.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iter.next();
        String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
        bundle.putString(key, value);
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.